# AS3 remove all instances of an object?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, instances

I have a game with in AS3 with a document class and a custom class which is attached to a movieclip in my .fla. Instances of that object are made multiple times/second. I want to delete those instances when, let's say, there are 100 of them. (because of performance problems after a while) The instances are stored in an Array after they are made.

Comment: So what's the problem, you have a reference to all of them in an array, you have some container (assuming they're Sprites/MovieClips/DisplayObjects/UIComponents of some sort) when the array.length is greater than 100 start unshifting the items from the beginning of the list and remove them from the container, you can re-use/recycle these instances or let them be garbage collected (re-use is better remember, reduce, re-use, recycle).  myArray.unshift() pulls the first item from the list (acting like a queue, FIFO first in first out)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove them by using `this.removeChild(obj);` and obj is your object from array. So what you need is to loop through array and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

That will remove all objects when objects are over 100.

```
if(array.length > 100)
{
  for(var i:int = array.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
  {
    stage.removeChild(array[i]);// or any other parent containing instances
    array.pop();
    //array[i] = null; // if you want to make them null instead of deleting from array
  }
}
```

---

Tip: Negative Loop (i--) is faster in performance than Positive Loop (i++).
Tip: pop() is faster in performance than unshift().

**Update**:

That will remove objects only if they are over 100, resulting in only 100 last objects remain on stage.

```
if(array.length > 100)
{
  for(var i:int = array.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
  {
    if(array.length > 100)
    {
      stage.removeChild(array[i]);// or any other parent containing instances
      array.unshift();// if you want to delete oldest objects, you must use unshift(), instead of pop(), which deletes newer objects
      //array[i] = null; // if you want to make them null instead of deleting from array
    }
}
```

Comment: is this better performance wise than unshift? also I would assume you don't want to actually empty the entire collection but rather remove the oldest references.

Answer (score 0):

```
/****** MyClass.as  *********/

public class MyClass extends Sprite{

    private var myVar:int=8567;

    private function myClass():void{
        //blablabla
    }

    public class destroy():void{
        myVar = null;
     this.removeFromParent(true); //method of Starling framework
    }
}


/********  Main.as  ****************/

public var myInstance:MyClass = new Myclass();

//Oh!! i need remove this instance D:

myInstance.destroy();
```